# How did Yusuf allow that his brother should be falsely implicated for theft?

Tags: tafseer, surat-yusuf, prophet-yusuf

When Yusuf (a.s.) wanted to keep his brother in Egypt he had a valuable measure bowl kept in the baggage of his brother. Then a person went into the caravan and shouted: O People of the caravan! You are thieves! Why did Yusuf (a.s.) act in this way that his brothers who had
come in the Caravan of Palestine should be implicated for theft? While false allegation and accusation is a sin and it is Haraam?

> فَلَمَّا جَهَّزَهُم بِجَهَازِهِمْ جَعَلَ السِّقَايَةَ فِي رَحْلِ
>   أَخِيهِ ثُمَّ أَذَّنَ مُؤَذِّنٌ أَيَّتُهَا الْعِيرُ إِنَّكُمْ
>   لَسَارِقُونَ
>    and when he had given them their provisions, he hid a
>   drinkingcup in his brother's saddlebag. then a herald called out after
>   them: 'cameleers, you are thieves!'

[[Surah Yusuf 12:70]](http://www.parsquran.com/data/showall.php?sura=12&ayat=%DB%B7%DB%B0&user=far&lang=eng)

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving my opinion on this :

if you recall the story of prophet Moses and EL khider, El Khider killed a child which we would consider to be wrong and a sin , but after knowing the reason  we are sure now he did the right thing. 
also prophets' acts are based on orders and knowledge from GOD ,so with our short knowledge we can't judge what seems wrong as a sin .